# rich:extendedDatatable adding an extra blank column at right end

Tags: richfaces

extendedDatatable adding an extra blank column at right end , how to remove this extra column ?

```xml
<rich:extendedDataTable width="100%"
value="#{entitlementean.conflictResolutions}" var="conflict"
sortMode="single" rowClasses="odd, even" rowKeyVar="row">

<rich:column width="50%">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputLabel value="product" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{conflict.productName}" />
</rich:column>

<rich:column " width="50%">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <hutputLabel value="function" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{conflict.conflictField}" />
</rich:column>
```

Comment: The extra column is inserted by RichFaces on purpose. But there seems to be a typo in your second column width declaration. If you fix that, both should be 50% and there shouldn't be an additional one

Answer (score 0):

I tried by removing the extra quote but see extra column even after that.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable width="100%"
value="#{entitlementean.conflictResolutions}" var="conflict"
sortMode="single" rowClasses="odd, even" rowKeyVar="row">

<rich:column width="50%">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputLabel value="product" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{conflict.productName}" />
</rich:column>

<rich:column width="50%">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <hutputLabel value="function" />
    </f:facet>

<h:outputLabel value="#{conflict.conflictField}" />
```

Comment: See following link:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11728

The Richfaces4 is not support % for column width ...
And so far I did not seen any workaround there.